# Communication between Service and any Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a code for send message from service to activity. But I only send message to the activity that create the service.
If I change the activity and service still active i need recive the messages in new activity. how?

I use this code:

**Activity**

```
public static Handler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();

...


    public static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            int state = message.arg1;
            switch (state) {
            case HIDE:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case SHOW:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I create service passing the handler.

```
Intent startService = new Intent(context, SERVICE.class)
startService.putExtra("MESSENGER", new Messenger(messageHandler));
context.startService(startService);
```

When change the activity I stop receiving messages. I can create a messageHandler class in any activity? thats work? Thanks!

Comment: you can implement services refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service

Comment: @sasikumar I took my code from this link. Of which answer you speak?

Comment: try this . http://stackoverflow.com/a/20595215/3981656

Comment: @Moti Bartov answer from that link

Comment: @Sathish Kumar J This answer it exacly my code. With this code, I can't recive the messages in other activity. or i'm wrong?

Comment: @sasikumar who is Moti? :) In this link are 3 good answers, one is my current code

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/30235369/2032561

Comment: @skadoosh If I binding activity and service, when I finish the activity the service is finished,n?

Comment: I need have a same service for all activities, ans can sent message to active activity in this moment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library:

Also read about `Observer pattern`.

Hope it helps!