# how to start commit Fragment in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used FireBase could messaging in my application and I want when the user receive message the activity fragment change. I did the following code for that but i don't know why it give me error on getFragmentManager that it because i don't have activity context or something like that.

```
public class googleFirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        switch (remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
        {
            case "invoices_ready":
                SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("invoices_ready",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("pr_id",remoteMessage.getData().get("pr_id").toString());
                editor.commit();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                transaction.replace(R.id.root_menu_fragment, new _step4_FragmentDrugInfo());
                transaction.addToBackStack("mapView");
                transaction.commit();
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
                break;
        }


    }

    private void showNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this , splash.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **broadcast** any firebase message updates and register broadcast receiver that handles that updates(where you should do fragment transactions) in your activity. If your activity is in the **foreground** that means luckily your receiver is **registered**. If you want to add the fragment in firebase service context, you can implement your own *android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks* interface, like

```
public class ActivityLifeCycleHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks { 
   Activity currentActivity;
   @Override
   public void onActivityResumed(Activity foregroundActivity) {
      this.currentActivity = foregroundActivity;
  }
}
```

And get your activity's reference from ActivityLifeCycleHandler class of yours.(be careful not to leak the activity) . I wouldn't recommend this solution thought.

This callback is registered for your application instance and its callbacks(**onResume()**) are triggered by *Activity* life-cycle methods(**super.onResume()**) for every activity in your application.

Answer (score 1):

`getFragmentManager()` is a method of `Activity`, therefore it can't work in a `Service`.

Comment: I know and said getFragmentManager is part of Activity but how can i bind it

Comment: There might be an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37322977/3527024
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get a reference to `getFragmentManager()` in the service class
How erver you can use a broadcast to listne the calls, anywhere else in the application.