# Passing entities string using Google NLP API to Main Activity (Android)

Tags: android, api, nlp, google-cloud-nl

I was able to pass a string (a sentence) to Google's NLP API (configured in a separate class called NLPService.java) from my Main Activity Class, but I want to be able to return the result (a certain entity string) from the NLPService Class back to my Main Activity for further processing. Is it possible for me to pass the entities string back to my Main Activity? In Android Studio, I have created a NLPService.java with the following code:

```
//New NLP Model
public void analyzeText(String textToAnalyze) {

    Document doc = new Document();
        doc.setContent(textToAnalyze)
            .setType("PLAIN_TEXT");

    final String[] result = new String[1];
    if (textToAnalyze != null && !doc.isEmpty()) {
        doc.setContent(textToAnalyze);
        //Config request to be sent to Google NLP
        Features features = new Features();
        features.setExtractEntities(true);

        final AnnotateTextRequest request = new AnnotateTextRequest();
        request.setDocument(doc);
        request.setFeatures(features);

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    returnResponse(NLPService.documents().annotateText(request).execute());
                    result[0] = returnResponse(NLPService.documents().annotateText(request).execute());
                    Log.i("getAsyncResponse", "RESULT: " + result[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}


public String returnResponse(AnnotateTextResponse response) {
    final List<Entity> entityList = response.getEntities();

    String entities = "";
    for (Entity entity : entityList) {
        entities += "\n" + entity.getName().toUpperCase() + " " + entity.getType();

    }
    return entities;

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The common approach will be using Broadcast (LocalBroadcastManager) to pass the data you intended to send from service to any activity.
[Example of Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322312/send-string-from-service-to-activity)
Or you can use SharedPreferences which is unlikely.