# Accessing a value from a service to an adapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, android-progressbar

In Service class :

```
public void onNotify(TransferHandler<ProcessHolder> handler, int percentage) {
    updateprocess(percentage);
}
```

in adapter

**onBindViewHolder**

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext());
progressBar = parentView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_process);
```

now I want to access percentage from service class method to this adapter progress

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37322906/6727154. And then look for the adapter method `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

After config that follow this steps

**1** : Create `servieClass.java`

```
public class serviceClass {

private int percentage;

public serviceClass(int percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
}

public int getPercentage() {
    return percentage;
}
}
```

**2** : Change service

```
public void onNotify(TransferHandler<ProcessHolder> handler, int percentage) {
   updateprocess(percentage);
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new servieClass(percentage));
}
```

**3** : add `setPercentage` function to your Adapter

```
public void setPercentage(int percentage){
    this.percentage = percentage;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**4** : Finally add this in fragment that you config EventBus in it

```
 @Subscribe
public void onEvent(BlockedEvent event) {
    adapter.setPercentage(percentage);
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the Service class I wrote this

```
public void onNotify(TransferHandler<ProcessHolder> handler, int percentage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("PercentageUpdates");
    intent.putExtra("percentage", percentage);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and at the Activity side you have to receive this Broadcast message

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("PercentageUpdates"));
```

By this way you can send percentage to an Activity. here mPercentageReceiver is the class in that class you will perform what ever you want....

```
private BroadcastReceiver mPercentageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String percentage = intent.getStringExtra("percentage");
        if (percentage != null) {
            // You can set the percentage here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for the response but i am using fragment and it's adapter ... percentage is always come with 0 response....