# Trying to pass data from a service to an activity

Tags: java, android

I have a string that I'm trying to pass to my main activity that is bound to this service. The data doesn't seem to be making it through to the other side and I've tried a plethora of techniques. Any help would be appreciated
Here's the service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String thename=intent.getStringExtra("stockName");
        String TAG="hello";
        Intent putIntent=new Intent(LocalService.this,Binding.class);
        if(thename.equals("AMZN"))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "The price is $1,755.25", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            putIntent.putExtra("theName","WORKED");
        }
```

and here is the activity itself

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_binding);
    final Button priceButton=findViewById(R.id.priceButton);
    final EditText stockPrice=findViewById(R.id.stockText);

    final Intent theIntent=new Intent(Binding.this,LocalService.class);
    priceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String stockText=stockPrice.getText().toString();
            theIntent.putExtra("stockName",stockText);
            startService(theIntent);
            Intent getit=getIntent();
            String name=getit.getParcelableExtra("theName");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I recommend you this link to do this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#sending-broadcasts and check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322312/send-string-from-service-to-activity. I hope this helps you

Comment: You never send the intent from the service. Atleast not in the code that  you provided. I would recommend to use a BroadcastReceiver that listens for your broadcasts from your service and send the data that  way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a BroadcastReceiver to your code  (it's not that pretty), I commented the lines I added. It's possible that I've missed something or made an error. Feel free to ask if  your get any errors or read  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

Good luck!

**Your service**

```
         public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       //String for the BroadcastReceiver to listen for.                
       public static final String BROADCAST_STRING = "your.package.or.whatever.you.want.sending";

                    String thename=intent.getStringExtra("stockName");
                    String TAG="hello";
                    Intent putIntent=new Intent(BROADCAST_STRING);
                    if(thename.equals("AMZN"))
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "The price is $1,755.25", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                putIntent.putExtra("theName","WORKED");
            }

            //Broadcast sent and  picked up in Activity.
            sendBroadcast(putIntent);
```

**Your Activity**

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_binding);
    final Button priceButton=findViewById(R.id.priceButton);
    final EditText stockPrice=findViewById(R.id.stockText);
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    final Intent theIntent=new Intent(Binding.this,LocalService.class);

    //Adds a filter to the broadcastReceiver, what it should listen for
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("your.package.or.whatever.you.want.sending");

    //Triggered when a broadcast is  picked up
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          //Get intent and do what you want
    };

    // Register the broadcastReceiver and filter
    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);


    priceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String stockText=stockPrice.getText().toString();
            theIntent.putExtra("stockName",stockText);
            startService(theIntent);
            Intent getit=getIntent();
            String name=getit.getParcelableExtra("theName");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```