# My app automatically going to onRestoreInstanceState android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, onrestoreinstancestate

I have an Android app which reads the data from HR monitor, In that when user doing workout my app is able get the data. Even app goes in the background it is getting data.

The problem here is when we open 7 to 8 apps and comes to my app the app is going to `onRestoreInstanceState`. On that case i will not any data and total connection is lost. How to maintain that state to solve that issue.

Comment: this may be due to memory issue so that android system kill your app in the background.

Comment: Ya.. is there any way to handle this type of issues. ?

Comment: first of all find is there any memory leak in your app.
Also are you reading this data in fragment or actvitiy.

Answer (score 0):

When you minimize or leave the Activity by opening next one it might be killed by the system. And [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is called when Activity is **re-initialized**. For getting data from a continuous connection you cannot relay on Activity. Because Activity may be destroyed or restarted when goes background. 
Consider using [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for this type of task. Service is designed for background and long running task when activity may not be alive. Use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to send data from Service to Activity. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351674/send-data-from-service-to-activity-android) link for communicating between Service and Activity.

Comment: I think my code is like that only. I written ble service and to get heartrate data I used broadcast. But after opening some 5-7 apps again coming to my app it's called reinitialized. My total workout data is lost.

Comment: Then you can store data in some persistence storage.