# Stop service when app goes to background, using a common Base Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a Base Activity class to implement common behaviour for all the Activities. All of them extend this BaseActivity.

I'm binding to a service in in the BaseActivity's onStart method and unbinding *conditionally* in the onStop method. With conditionally, I mean that depending on some option selected by the user, the service should or should not keep running in the background when the app goes to background.

The problem is that sometimes the service keeps running when it shouldn't (this is, when the option for killing it is enabled, and unbindService() is effectively called).

I'm thinking that on every Activity change the service is unbound and bound again. Since bound services are reference counted, maybe my service is bound more times than unbound, so that's why it keeps running at the end, even when I call unbindService().

Additionally, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding) says something about that:

> You should usually pair the binding and unbinding during matching bring-up and tear-down moments of the client's lifecycle. For example:
>
> If you only need to interact with the service while your activity is visible, you should bind during onStart() and unbind during onStop().
>
> If you want your activity to receive responses even while it is stopped in the background, then you can bind during onCreate() and unbind during onDestroy(). Beware that this implies that your activity needs to use the service the entire time it's running (even in the background), so if the service is in another process, then you increase the weight of the process and it becomes more likely that the system will kill it.

Since I'm kind of trying to implement both options, what should be the best approach to implement this?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485342/how-to-handle-ipc-between-a-service-and-an-activity-and-its-subactivity/10519846#10519846) I think that is a better approach than constantly binding/unbinding

Comment: My answer is wrong please uncheck so I can delete it.

Comment: The link for that "somewhere" is http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed my approach and decided to use only `startService()` and communicate with the service using a Local Broadcast Receiver.

I start the service in the `onCreate()` and stop it in the `onDestroy()` methods of the Base Activity.
Then, to send a message from the Service to the activity, I use this:

```
private void sendBroadcastMessage(String msg) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "send broadcast message: " + msg);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.class.getSimpleName());
    // Add data
    intent.putExtra("message", msg);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Then, to be notified in the activity:

```
// handler for the events launched by the service
private BroadcastReceiver mMyServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got message: " + message);
        // Do stuff...
    }
};
```

And to register the Receiver in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMonitorReceiver,
          new IntentFilter(MyService.class.getSimpleName()));
}
```